# Jmeter: String Index Out of Bounds Exceptions on Xpath

Tags: jmeter

Can some one please please help me on this. I am tired of looking into it.

In while loop I am reading data from csv file, navigate to web pages and get Xpath values.

I get String Index out of bounds exceptions on Xpath.

[Please see this screenshot of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sgrW.jpg)

Steps to execute were

```
1.dealers.tt -- HTTP request
2.edit_integrtaion_details.tt --- HTTP request
3.Dealer details -- HTTP Request
   then Xpath entities under Dealer details
```

For some reason some of the records read from file... only 2 steps get executed as below.leaving other steps (3 and Xpath)
 dealers.tt
 edit_integrtaion_details.tt

then I get an error as 
'Dealer details' : java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8193

I tried selecting redirect automatically and follow redirects in HTTP requests to force step 3 to execute. In both cases get this error.There are no spaces for the name I get from Xpath

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are sufferin from [JTidy issue #205](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtidy/bugs/205/), the options are in:

1. Uncheck "Use Tidy" box, if your response is valid XML or XHTML it might be the case you don't need it (unlikely though)
2. Compile latest JTidy from the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtidy/code/HEAD/tree/) and once done replace `jtidy-r938.jar` in "lib" folder of your JMeter installation with the brand new JTidy jar.
3. Switch to [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
4. Switch to [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
5. If XPath is totally a must you can also consider [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/), it [has built-in support of some form of XPath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath). Check out [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.

Comment: I get output with space next to Dealers Name value. Could it be the cause of white space.(LUTHER BROOKDALE TOYOTA (TOYOTACITY) ,)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Dealers Name,Count of Deferred Transactions,Transaction Errors,Integration Exists
LUTHER BROOKDALE TOYOTA (TOYOTACITY) ,0,2,true

Comment: Also jtidy-r938 this is the latest version I see

Comment: //td[@class="dealertitle"]/text()/normalize-space(.)-- I use this to remove white spaces i text. Why do I get an error ?                                                            Unknown nodetype: normalize-space